# Angular2 :: NgFor :: Promises

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a service that selectively loads some data and caches it in memory at the same time. If the same data is requested later, the service returns the cached copy. The method to retrieve the data from the service returns a `Promise`:

```
export class MyService {

  users = [];

  getSingleUser(id: string): Promise<User> {
    if (this.users[id]) return Promise.resolve(this.users[id]);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.fetchUserFromNetwork(id)
        .then(user => {
          this.users[id] = user;
          resolve(user);
        })
    })
  }

  getUsersList(idList: string[]): Promise<User[]> {
    return Promise.all(idList.map(id => this.getSingleUser(id)));
  }

}
```

I have another object which contains the list of `userId`s to be displayed.

```
export class MyReport {
  userIds = [];
  addUserId(id: string) { this.userIds.push(id) }
}
```

Now I want to render this information inside a template. In the component class, I have a reference to a singleton instance of `MyReport` (`this.report`) as well as a singleton instance of `MyService` (`this.service`). UI controls in **OTHER** pages allow the EndUser to add/remove the list of `userIds` inside the `this.report` instance.

To render the list, I use:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of (this.service.getUsersList(this.report.userIds) | async)">
  User: {{ user | json }}
</div>
```

However, this ends up calling `MyService.getUsersList(...)` an infinite number of times. So much so, that the browser thread effectively hangs.

How can I resolve this issue? I think the issue is this: Angular2 calls `this.service.getUsersList(...)`, passes it thru `async` pipe to get the list, and renders it. It then calls the same method again to see if the ChangeDetection cycle is complete. However, the array reference has changed, even though the data is unchanged. So it keeps doing it over and over again.

My objectives are as follows:

1. Render the data returned by the promise: `this.service.getUsersList(this.report.userIds)`
2. Automatically update the rendered list if `this.report.userIds` is modified anywhere in the application.
3. Not end up in infinite loops. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promise.all creates a promise everytime you execute the function.
You can simply create a variable to hold the value instead of creating it each time

```
  private _usersPromise: Promise<User[]>;
  getUsersList(idList: string[]): Promise<User[]> {
    if(this._usersPromise) return this._usersPromise;
    return this._usersPromise = Promise.all(idList.map(id => this.getSingleUser(id)));
  }
```

Comment: I think I'd also have to cache `idList` as well. If the list hasn't changed, then I return the last created promise. The question now becomes: How does one check that the array contents are still the same? A `for` loop iterating thru the entire array comes to mind. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can't. This is a promise of the array. Not the actual Array. To actually check if the array has changed you'd need to resolve it.